# return the text entered in a QTableWidget

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, qt-designer

I am creating a plugin in Qgis and I need to enter values to a QTableWidget through the interface, but I cannot find a function that returns them to me.
I do not do it with a LineEdit because I need the number of spaces to fill out equal to those of a listWidget.
try to do it with QTableWidget itemAt but the return is a QTableWidgetItem.
the code is the following:

```py
def Input_shape (self):
    filefolder= QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.dlg, "", "/desktop") 
    filename = glob.glob(filefolder+"/"+"\\*.shp") 
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear() 
    self.dlg.listWidget.clear()
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems([filefolder])
    self.dlg.listWidget.addItems(filename)
    self.dlg.tableWidget.clear()
    self.dlg.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(filename))
    self.dlg.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

def run(self):
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
    self.dlg = SubsueloDialog()
    self.dlg.boton_entrada.clicked.connect(self.Input_shape)
    filefolder= self.dlg.comboBox_2.currentText() 
    filenames = glob.glob(filefolder+"/"+"\\*.shp") 
    limites= self.dlg.tableWidget.item(1,1)
```

The interface looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Connect to your buttons `Aceptar` and `Cancelar` signals, see the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: You want to get the value of the cell in row 1 of column 1 ?

Comment: FOR NOW I WAS TESTING IT WITH THAT, BUT THE IDEA IS TO USE A CYCLE THAT RETURNS ALL THE CELLS

Comment: J. Monticolo the buttons are connected in another class, I included only the code fragment that I still haven't solved

Answer (score 2):

In following code, you have an example where you can get all values typed in a **QTableWidget** object by using a function connected to a **QPushButton**.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Dlg(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.label1 = QLabel('FERTILIZACION SUBSUELO')
        self.btn = QPushButton('RUN')
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(100)

        nb_row = 5
        nb_col = 2

        #creating empty table
        data = [ [] for i in range(nb_row) ]

        for i in range(nb_row):
            for j in range(nb_col):
                data[i].append('')

        self.table1 = QTableWidget()

        self.table1.setRowCount(nb_row)
        self.table1.setColumnCount(nb_col)
        self.table1.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['LIMITE 1', 'LIMITE 2'])

        for row in range (nb_row):
            for col in range(nb_col):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
                self.table1.setItem(row, col, item)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table1, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, 2, 0)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.print_table_values)

    def print_table_values(self, data):

        nb_row = 5
        nb_col = 2

        for row in range (nb_row):
            for col in range(nb_col):
                print(row, col, self.table1.item(row, col).text())

w = Dlg()
w.resize(350,300)
w.setWindowTitle('fertilizacion_abono')
w.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
w.show()
```

After running the code, I got a Dialog similar to yours where I typed arbitrary values for each **QTableWidgetItem** objects.

[image]

After clicking RUN button, **print_table_values** function printed in Python Console all values as expected.

[image]

Comment: Hi Xunilk, thank you very much for responding. I have worked on the code to adjust it to the add-in and I still cannot save the values entered in the table in a list of the main method, instead of printing them on the console. (I didn't have to use the QPushButton because I'm running it in the run method)

Comment: My code is only an example. I printed the values to Python Console only for showing that it works. I don't know what do you want to do with your data but, normally, plugin methods are placed before run method. For this reason there are other commentaries pointed out that you should connect your buttons Aceptar and Cancelar as signals. By the way, is it your first plugin?

Comment: I will keep it in mind, thank you very much. and yes, it is my first complement